# Regular Expression Specific Email Domain(preg_match)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am new to regular expressions and need some help. I need to use a regular expression to validate an email so it has a specific email so only emails ending in @School.edu work, as of right now i have

```
    $username = $_REQUEST["username"];
    $password = $_REQUEST["pass"];
    $repeatP = $_REQUEST["repeat"];
    //Username is Acceptable, Passwords Match and Appropirate Size
    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\oneonta.edu$/i", $username)) {
        $userCheck = true; 
        ?> <p>Username is Acceptable</p>
        <?
    }
    else {
        ?><p>Error: Username is Unacceptable, Please go back and try again</p> 
        <?
    }
```

I'm using School.edu as an example for my schools edu, I just don't get how to it only allow School.edu emails

Comment: Do you have a list of allowed schools or domains?

Comment: strpos() , to just check if one string contains another is far more efficient or split on @ and do a straight string compare (==)

Comment: Do you just want to know if "@School.edu work" exists in the email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option:

```
$mystring = '@oneonta.edu';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $_REQUEST["username"]);

if ($pos !== false) {
     echo "<p>Username is Acceptable</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p>Error: Username is Unacceptable, Please go back and try again</p> ";
}
```

another

```
 if(substr($_REQUEST["username"], -12)=='@oneonta.edu'){
     echo "<p>Username is Acceptable</p>";
}else{
    echo "<p>Error: Username is Unacceptable, Please go back and try again</p> ";
}
```

more ?

```
   $pieces = explode("@", $_REQUEST["username"]);

     if($pieces[1]=='oneonta.edu'){
         echo "<p>Username is Acceptable</p>";
    }else{
        echo "<p>Error: Username is Unacceptable, Please go back and try again</p> ";
    }
```